# Spring 3 and Hibernate 4 configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm trying to implement the new Spring 3 and Hibernate 4 integration, using declarative transaction management. But there is very less documentation on the net. I'm always getting an error:

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

This is how may datasource config looks like:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true;upgrade=true"/>
        <property name="username" value="******"/>
        <property name="password" value="******"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.rpm.domain" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties"> 
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
    <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" /> 
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>

<bean id="userAccountDAO" class="com.rpm.dao.impl.UserAccountDAO" />
```

Comment: look at this sample:http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/jsf-2-primefaces-3-spring-3-hibernate-4.html

Answer (score 0):

hello in my current project I'm using this configuration:
Spring 3 framework 3.2.3.RELEASE + Hibernate 4.2.3 + MySQL 5

Below my pom.xml, it work very good!

I hope it can help you:

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.springframework.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.3.Final</hibernate.version>
    <junit.version>4.5</junit.version>
    <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring MVC depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-remoting</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>context</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the hibernate-configuration.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't enabled annotation based transaction. how do you implement **UserAccountDAO**? and which line thrown the exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.zeronetribe.context.model</value>
            <value>com.zeronetribe.context.model.graph</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```